# Is there a way to include php variables in a curl_setopt url?

Tags: php, curl

I can get the JSON file from a weather site, using numeric value of latitude and longitude of a location with this code:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://weathersite.xyz/complete.json?lat=38.59&lon=-8.43');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
 $fIOURL = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch) ;
```

However, what I really want is to use php variables ($latitude and $longitude) instead of these numeric values in the url, but when I try to replace them it doesn't work.
As an example,

```
 $latitude="38.50";
 $longitude="-8.43";
 ....
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://weathersite.xyz/complete.json?lat={$latitude}&lon={longitude}");
 ....
```

I also tried all possibilities of single and double quoting the variables in the url like I do in html, but nothing seems to work with curl_setopt.
Is there any solution for including php variables inside a url in curl_setopt?

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? The URL you are calling is a string like all others

Comment: This has nothing to do with URLs specifically, just learn how to concatenate a string

Comment: @esquew thanks. I am very familiar with single and double quoting strings in php, and I have tried all possibilities but this url only works with numeric values and gives no response if I replace them by php variables.

Comment: Then you need to share more details. The code you've shown doesn't even declare values for these two variables

Comment: Please show what you tried then, exactly. Because the version you've shown us using variables also uses a single quoted string, which, as you claim you already know, won't interpolate the PHP variables within it. I feel that if you really already knew that, you wouldn't have tried it like that.

Comment: Have you tried generating the URL first, write it to a variable, and dump that? This could help to spot the problem

Comment: Thanks for the update. `&lon={longitude}` ...typo, should be `&lon={$longitude}`. Then it works fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5c8effcadf56a1556f3f58d1e459580bff82454

Comment: @Nico Hasse thanks I spotted the problem. Lat and long could not be more than 4 decimals and I was using 6!

Comment: Ah so basically you showed us sample data which didn't actually reproduce the issue. And it was nothing to do with generating the URL, it was the specific content which was the problem, causing the request to fail (rather than the URL string to be incorrectly generated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct type of quotes:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://weathersite.xyz/complete.json?lat={$latitude}&lon={$longitude}");
```

The curly braces are not a must in this case. I just added them for readability.

Here are some more details regarding [string concatenation in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.operators.string.php)

[This note explains your case exactly](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.operators.string.php#110937)